# Classify all matrices $A,B$ such that $AB\ne BA$, but there is some $n>1$ such that $(AB)^n=(BA)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Recently when teaching the basics of matrices, a student asked if there are matrices $A,B$ for which $AB\ne BA$, but for some $n>1$ we have $(AB)^n = (BA)^n$? I was able to come up with a few cases where the answer is yes.

- If both $AB$ and $BA$ are nilpotent, then the result is obvious; take $n$ to be the maximum power that kills both.
- Another nice case is if $A,B$ are rotation matrices in dimension $d\ge 3$ (so they don't commute) and are both rotations by rational multiples of $2\pi$. In particular, the case where $d=3$ and $A$ is a rotation about the $x$-axis by $\pi/2$ and $B$ is a rotation about the $y$-axis by $\pi/2$ readily gives $AB\ne BA$ but $(AB)^3=(BA)^3=I$. The student is a fan of Rubik's Cubes so I think this will make a nice example.
- My gut says other geometric-flavored matrices (i.e., reflections) will also have this property.

However, I want to ask a follow-up question, namely to classify all such matrices with this property. Writing $A=PS P^{-1}$ and $B=PT P^{-1}$ for some matrix $P$ is intractable, as we have
$$
(AB)^n = P (ST)^n P^{-1} ; (BA)^n = P(TS)^n P^{-1},
$$which gets us nowhere. Is there some nice classification of these matrices?

Comment: Representations for all non-abelian finite groups is the natural extension of your 2nd point

Comment: @user8675309 I understand, that’s a very nice point. These are always representable by matrices by Cayley’s Theorem, as the group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. A user previously commented something about Artin-Tits groups; maybe the infinite groups are classified that way?

Comment: My comment was not limited to faithful representations.  Pick your favorite finite non-abelian group and (working over $\mathbb C$) any representation that includes a $d\geq 2$ irreducible will serve up an example.

Comment: Must we have $\det(A),\det(B)\in \{0,-1,1\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but more than an extended comment.

If $A$ is invertible, then $AB$ and $BA$ are conjugate.  We have $(AB)^n=(A(BA)A^{-1})^n=A(BA)^nA^{-1}$, so $(AB)^n=(BA)^n$ if and only if $A$ commutes with $(BA)^n$.  Hence, we are looking for $A$ such that $A$ does not commute with $BA$ but does commute with $(BA)^n$.

Using this, if $A$ is invertible and $BA$ is diagonalizable, then one can show that we can change basis such that $A$ and $BA$ are both block diagonal, with the blocks of $BA$ not necessarily scalar, but with some power of them scalar.  For example, if $D=\operatorname{diag}(2,-2,3,-3)$, $A$ is invertible and of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & 0 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e & f \\ 0 & 0 & g & h\end{pmatrix}$$

then we can set $B=DA^{-1}$

Then $AB\neq BA$ but $(AB)^{2}=(BA)^{2}$.  I assert that every example where $A$ is invertible and $BA$ is digaonalizable is conjugate to an example of this form.

There are similar examples one can produce when $BA$ isn't diagonalizable but has eigenvalues whose ratio is a root of unity, but I don't yet feel confident that I have a complete characterization in this case.

If neither $A$ nor $B$ is invertible, a necessary condition is that the [eventual images and eventual kernels](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/12/the_eventual_image.html) of $AB$ and $BA$ coincide, at which point I believe the problem boils down to whether the invertible parts of $AB$ and $BA$ satisfy the condition, although I have not fully verified this.

Comment: This is a neat answer. I'll look over it more but it seems you got more out of diagonalizing than I did.